# Importing HEX and Text data from one file into Matlab

Tags: matlab, text, hex

I am trying to read in a txt file which has a combination of hexadecimal data and text. I want to convert the hex to decimal except and then manipulate. Here is some sample data.

> x 0:47950   0x----    0x----  001:00:07:56.633300 9-R-04-04 0x8000
>   0x0012    0x0000 0x0000
>
> x 0:136994 0x---- 0x----  001:00:13:14.350422 8-R-05-04 0x8000
>   0x0012    0x0000 0x0000
>
> x 0:532637 0x---- 0x----  001:00:40:29.861743 7-R-06-04 0x8000
>   0x0012    0x0000 0x0000

The first four columns are kind of useless here ('x 0:47950   0x----    0x----') but the timestamp, tag (9-R-04-04), and hex are what I want to look at. Any help on how to get Matlab to read this data in and convert the hex to decimal would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just googled "matlab hex to decimal" and here is the first result: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html
And if you want to know how to read a text file:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html

Comment: Have you tried `textscan` with `%x` for hex numbers?

Answer (score 0):

```
% open and read the entire file
fid = fopen('temp.txt');
A = fread(fid);
fclose(fid);
% convert to text strings
txt = char(A)';
% create a cell array of lines
regexp(txt,'\n','split')
lines = regexp(txt,'\n','split');
% match the desired text
desTextCell = regexp(lines,'\d{3}:.+','match');
out = cellfun( @(x) regexp(x,'\s','split'), desTextCell);
out =
   {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}     {}
out{1}{:}

ans = 

  Columns 1 through 5

    '001:00:07:56.633300'    '9-R-04-04'    '0x8000'    '0x0012'    '0x0000'

  Columns 6 through 7

    '0x0000'     ''
```

You'll need to filter out the empty cells, reshape it, etc, but that's a quick and dirty solution for you.

Comment: thanks for the help guys! but for some reason, this part of the solution above is not working for me: out =
   {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}     {}
out{1}{:}

Answer (score 0):

You can import everything with `fscanf()`, as long as the tag is **fixed width** (here 9 chars). I skip the first 4 strings, then I import the timestamp separating days(?), hours, minutes, seconds with milliseconds (such that you can feed it to `datenum`), then I import the 9 chars of the tag mapped to ASCII positions and finally the four hex numbers:

```
fid  = fopen('test.txt');
data = fscanf(fid, '%*s %*s %*s %*s %f:%f:%f:%f %s %x %x %x %x',[17,inf])';
fclose(fid);
tag = cellstr(char(data(:,5:13)));
```

Note that, you have a total of 17 fields, 4 for the timestamp, 9 'chars' for the tag and the 4 hex numbers, but you can delete the numbers corresponding to the tag in `data` after converting it to a cellstring.